# New version BizTalk project deployment

Tags: deployment, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I tried to deploy a new version of my BizTalk project. After the deployment, I can see there are 2 different version of assemblies in the resource. However, when I tried to start the orchestration, I always got the error message about "cannot find the file", seems BizTalk cannot find my new version assembly. I am wondering there probably something wrong with the deployment. Any one has idea? thanks a lot

Comment: Is the assembly you're referring to one you created and added to the .msi?

Comment: if your problem is solved please return here and put here correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your new assembly is in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with BizTalk solutions we don't increment the Assembly Version of the projects but rather just the Assembly File Version otherwise you have to update all your references.

For example if you update the project that contains schemas, then you have to update all your maps, Orchestrations and Pipelines that you want to reference the new version of the schema to point to this assembly.

Incrementing just the file version does not break the deployment, and you only get one version in the GAC, but you can still see the Assembly File Version number to tell which build it is from.

There is one scenario where you do want to update your Assembly Version, and that is if you want both the old version and the new version deployed simultaneously.  To achieve this you have to follow the [Checklist: Updating an Application Using Side-by-Side Versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308960(v=bts.10).aspx)